# Does swift have a protocol for writing a stream of bytes?

Tags: io, swift, outputstream

I can't find anything in the Swift book about io. Is there any generic protocol similar to Java's OutputStream or Go's Writer interface for writing a stream of bytes? If you are writing a class that returns a stream, do you need to write your own protocol or use an Objective C protocol?

To be clear am asking for a Swift native interface for this not because I avoiding using Objective C or Cocoa, but for a description of the expected behavior for Swift to Swift code going forward.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/CocoaStreamsOverview.html

Comment: Seems odd you don't have something this basic as part of the standard library. The NSStream really isn't how you would do it if you wrote it in swift.

Comment: I agree Swift is lacking in this area at the moment but it is designed to work with Cocoa frameworks. is there something specific you are trying to do?

Comment: @tony Very curious - why would you not use NSStream? I don't think that just because Swift is around doesn't mean Cocoa is going away. I'd say it's a very legitimate way to work with streams in Swift.

Comment: @macandyp No I will use NSStream and of course it is legitimate way to do it. It just doesn't seems very idiomatic. I was expecting to need to use cocoa regularly for particular uses but there really no examples of the swift way to do io. How do you return errors without nserror, when to use optionals, etc. Even if barely anything implements the swift writer protocol, if I writing something new, I want to use that instead of the Obj C way. It really about implementation vs protocol. I could be writing both the reader and the writer, and want to know the native way to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is something the Swift docs are quiet about and I wanted to know more about so I looked into it.

There is a protocol, it's called `Streamable`:

```
protocol Streamable {
    func writeTo<Target : OutputStream>(inout target: Target)
}
```

`OutputStream`:

```
protocol OutputStream {
    func write(string: String)
}
```

`write` allows an object to be written to.

`String` conforms to both, making it easy to write to and from:

```
var target = String()
"this is a message".writeTo(&target)
println(target)
// this is a message
```

Writing to a file:

```
var msg = "this will be written to an output file"
msg.writeToFile("output.txt", atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
// creates 'output.txt' in the same folder as the executable
```

There is also `writeToUrl`.

I assume those functions are all built on top of Cocoa streams, which have similar functionality:

```
var os = NSOutputStream(toFileAtPath: "output.txt", append: true)
os.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

var msg = "a truly remarkable message"
var ptr:CConstPointer<UInt8> = msg.nulTerminatedUTF8

os.open()
os.write(ptr, maxLength: msg.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
os.close()
```

Comment: Nice find. It seems like they are still working it which is reassuring.

Comment: Note that the protocols have been renamed to [`TextOutputStreamable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/textoutputstreamable)  and [`TextOutputStream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/textoutputstream) in Swift 5 (and 4 too I think)